# Find attributes from list of dicts where a record is duplicated

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts. I wish to find all unique records by a field `id` and take the different attributes from various different occurrences of it.

The original list:

```
[{"id": "chehjkndskns", "att_a" : 12, "time" : 4},{"id": "chehjkndskns", "att_a" : 15, "time" : 5}, {"id": "sjnd", "att_a" : 14, "time" : 4},{"id": "sjnd", "att_a" : 166, "time" : 5}]
```

The desired outcome:

```
[{"id": "chehjkndskns", "attributes" : [{"att_a" : 12, "time" :4},{"att_a" : 15, "time" : 5}], {"id": "sjnd", "attributes" : [{"att_a" : 14, "time" :4},{"att_a" : 166, "time" : 5}]]
```

Comment: Is it necessary to remove the `id` field from the dicts in the desired outcome?

Comment: No, happy to leave it there if that is simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is straightforward to produce a dictionary that maps the `id`s of the input list to the corresponding objects:

```
from collections import defaultdict

original = [{"id": "chehjkndskns", "att_a" : 12, "time" : 4},{"id": "chehjkndskns", "att_a" : 15, "time" : 5}, {"id": "sjnd", "att_a" : 14, "time" : 4},{"id": "sjnd", "att_a" : 166, "time" : 5}]

result = defaultdict(lambda: [])    
for val in original:
    result[val["id"]] += [val]

print(result)
# {'sjnd': [{'att_a': 14, 'time': 4, 'id': 'sjnd'}, {'att_a': 166, 'time': 5, 'id': 'sjnd'}], 'chehjkndskns': [{'att_a': 12, 'time': 4, 'id': 'chehjkndskns'}, {'att_a': 15, 'time': 5, 'id': 'chehjkndskns'}]}
```

If you really want the result in the array format you described, you can simply add an extra step to transform this:

```
result = [{"id": key, "attributes": val} for key, val in result.items()]

print(result)
# [{'attributes': [{'time': 4, 'att_a': 12, 'id': 'chehjkndskns'}, {'time': 5, 'att_a': 15, 'id': 'chehjkndskns'}], 'id': 'chehjkndskns'}, {'attributes': [{'time': 4, 'att_a': 14, 'id': 'sjnd'}, {'time': 5, 'att_a': 166, 'id': 'sjnd'}], 'id': 'sjnd'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 =[{"id": "chehjkndskns", "att_a" : 12, "time" : 4},
        {"id": "chehjkndskns", "att_a" : 15, "time" : 5},
        {"id": "sjnd", "att_a" : 14, "time" : 4},
        {"id": "sjnd", "att_a" : 166, "time" : 5}]

new_list = map(lambda d: [{'id': d['id'],'attributes': [{'att_a': d['att_a'], 'time':d['time']}]}], list1)
```